# Will app lose the NSUserDefault data on over the air installation?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, keychain, over-the-air

Will app lose the **NSUSerDefaults** values when I do over the air installation?

1. No app installed in the device
2. Install the app version 1.0 over the air and saving some values in **NSUserDefaults**
3. Install the app version 1.0 over the air again with out deleting the app.
4. **Will I lose the NSUSerDefaults values because of installing the same version?**

Comment: If you do not delete then it will not be deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever you have in `NSUserDefaults` it remains in the device/system. It never gets deleted even when you upgrade your app however on uninstalling or manually deletion it is removed.

Answer (score 4):

`NSUserDefaults` does not reset unless the user deletes the app. So they persists on Update.

Hope this answers your question.